# Invocar evento OnClick de un asp:LinkButton desde JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp, eventos

Necesito invocar al método de cierre de sesión desde JavaScript (una vez que el contador del sistema llegue a 0).
Código de la vista:

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    ID="Lbtn_Salir" 
    type="button" 
    runat="server" 
    OnClick="Lbtn_Salir_Click" 
    OnClientClick="Lbtn_Salir_Click">
    Salir
</asp:LinkButton>
```

El código asociado a dicha vista:

```
public void os(string value, object target)
{
    Session[value] = target;
}

protected void Lbtn_Salir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    os("ID_USER", null);
    os("MENU", null);
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx", false);
}
```

Cuando el botón es presionado por el usuario las variables de sesión se destruyen correctamente y el aplicativo lo envía hacia la página de inicio. 
Lo que deseo es reutilizar dicha función desde algún script sin embargo no ocurre nada una vez que invoco al evento click asociado al botón **Salir**.

```
function salir(){
    // Reloj llega a 0

    // Método 1
    var btn_salir = $("#Lbtn_Salir");
    btn_salir.click();

    // Método 2
    $('#btn_salir').trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción podría ser:

```
function salir() {
    __doPostBack('Lbtn_Salir', '');
}
```

Y en tu .cs, en el Page_Load:

```
if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "Lbtn_Salir")
{    
    Lbtn_Salir_Click(this, new EventArgs());    
}
```

Y ejecutar la función salir donde quieras.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, tu solución funcionó perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta en el script, deberías quitar la función y poner:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Reloj llega a 0

    // Método 1
    var btn_salir = $("#Lbtn_Salir");
    btn_salir.click();

    // Método 2
    $('#btn_salir').trigger('click');
});
```

De esta manera ya podrás leer la función del botón onclick.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.